# Gradient layer on tableview cell prevention selection colour from appearing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I tried to spruce my application up a bit by adding a CGGradientLayer to my tableview cells, and the code works great.

Only problem is that, now, whenever I select a tableview cell, it does not change colour to the selection style, whether blue or grey.

The code I am using for my gradient is

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = view.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.3  blue:0.3 alpha:1.0] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.28 green:0.28 blue:0.28 alpha:1.0] CGColor], nil];
[cell.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

I do know that my cell is being selected as the text in my cells changes colour to white, which is the default selection colour.

So what I am trying to fix is the selection colour on my cells. I don't mind if I can't use the selection colours provided, but in that case can I maybe add my own transparent rect over the cell on selection?

Comment: What are you doing with the view? I assume you can select the cell as you want it to when you delete this code, right?

Comment: Couldn't you just animate the opacity of the gradient layer when a row gets selected? There is a delegate method -tableView:DidSelectRowAtIndexPath: where you get a callback whenever a row is selected. (You'd also have to animate the opacity back in -tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: (note the DEselect) to get the right effect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a UITableViewCell is selected, it inserts the selection background at index 0.  That ends up being under your gradient.  The view hierarchy looks like this:

```
<MyTableViewCell: 0xd26fb80; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 44; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xd26fc90>>
   | <UITableViewCellSelectedBackground: 0x6880810; frame = (0 0; 320 43); layer = <CALayer: 0x68855c0>>
   | <CAGradientLayer: 0xd26ecb0> (layer)
   | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0xd26fcc0; frame = (0 0; 320 43); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd26fd00>>
   | <UIView: 0xd26e8e0; frame = (0 43; 320 1); autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0xd26f1a0>>
```

Notice that the `CAGradientLayer`, which I inserted at index zero when the cell was created, is after `UITableViewCellSelectedBackground`, so the gradient layer overlays the selected background layer visually.

To fix it, make your own subclass of `UITableViewCell`.  Make the gradient layer a property or ivar of your subclass:

```
@implementation MyTableViewCell
{
    CAGradientLayer *_gradient;
}

- (void)initGradient
{
    _gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    _gradient.opaque = YES;
    _gradient.frame = self.bounds;
    _gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(__bridge id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, (__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor, nil];
    [self.layer insertSublayer:_gradient atIndex:0];
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) {
        [self initGradient];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self initGradient];
}
```

Override `setSelected:animated:` in your subclass to show or hide the gradient layer based on whether the cell is selected:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    _gradient.hidden = selected;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have implemented parts of your code and taken advice in making my own subclass for UITableViewCell, but now, when the cell is held down, not selected yet, just held down, the cell's text changes colour (highlighted colour), but the cell does not until the user takes their finger off the cell. This isn't too much of an issue to me, but since the text colour is similar to the cell colour, it seems as if the text disappears for a little while... Any ideas?

Comment: Look at the `highlightedTextColor` property of `UILabel`.  If that's not sufficient, override `setHighlighted:animated:` in your `UITableViewCell` subclass and do whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

I came upon this same problem, and since `- (void)setSelected:animated:` was not always called (such as when the user holds down on the cell, etc.) I found this method to work much better.

Essentially, just put your gradient in the `cell.backgroundView`.

```
UIView *cellBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = cellBackgroundView.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.3 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.28 green:0.28 blue:0.28 alpha:1.0] CGColor], nil];

[cellBackgroundView.layer addSublayer:gradient];
cell.backgroundView = cellBackgroundView;
```

And then set your `selectedBackgroundView` to however you want. this way, the cell's backgroundView is sure to be completely hidden, layers and all. This also works with subclassing, replace `cell.` with `self.`.